# How to use glDebugMessageControl

Tags: c++, opengl

This is based on the debug callback example from https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output and somewhat on https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Debugging.

Setting up the callback:

```
void GLAPIENTRY
MessageCallback( GLenum source,
                 GLenum type,
                 GLuint id,
                 GLenum severity,
                 GLsizei length,
                 const GLchar* message,
                 const void* userParam )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "GL CALLBACK: %s type = 0x%x, severity = 0x%x, message = %s\n",
           ( type == GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR ? "** GL ERROR **" : "" ),
            type, severity, message );
}
```

And then, after window creation ect., registering it:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE);
glEnable              ( GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT );    

if(glDebugMessageCallback){
    std::cout << "Register OpenGL debug callback " << std::endl;
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);
    GLuint unusedIds = 0;
    //glDebugMessageCallback( MessageCallback, 0 ); also tried setting up the callback here
    glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE,
                          GL_DONT_CARE,
                          GL_DONT_CARE,
                          0,
                          &unusedIds,
                          GL_TRUE);
    glDebugMessageCallback( MessageCallback, 0 );
}
else
    std::cout << "glDebugMessageCallback not available" << std::endl;
```

After that I produce an error message by calling

```
glClear(GL_DEPTH);
```

which works as expected. It's source is `GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API`.
However, if i set

```
glDebugMessageControl(GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION,
                              GL_DONT_CARE,
                              GL_DONT_CARE,
                              0,
                              &unusedIds,
                              GL_TRUE);
```

the callback is still emitted, even though, as I understand, it should not be because of the `GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION` filter.
This also occurs for other combinations of filters, so that I assume that the call to `glDebugMessageControl` has no effect in my implementation.

Has anyone an idea what I'm missing here?
Thank you!

Comment: If you want to **disable** reporting of specific debug messages, then the last parameter of [`glDebugMessageControl`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glDebugMessageControl) has to be `GL_FALSE`.

Comment: This works, so the call has an effect. But this disables messages that match the filter. I would like to disable message that do not match the filter, where `GL_TRUE` should be used?

Comment: This is not possible. By `glDebugMessageControl` you can explicitly specify messages, whose state (enabled/disables) you want to change. But there is no function, which changes the state of all the other messages which are not specified in the filter which you pass to `glDebugMessageControl`.

Comment: Okay, so I totally missunderstood this call, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [`glDebugMessageControl`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glDebugMessageControl) you can explicitly specify messages, whose state (enabled/disabled) you want to change. But there is no possibility to change the state of all the other messages, which are not specified in the filter, which is passed to `glDebugMessageControl`.

If you want to disable reporting of specific debug messages, then the last parameter of `glDebugMessageControl` (`enabled`) has to be `GL_FALSE`.

Furthermore, `glClear(GL_DEPTH)` would cause a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error and the source type is `GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API`, instead of `GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION`:

```
glDebugMessageControl(
    GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API,
    GL_DONT_CARE,
    GL_DONT_CARE,
    0, NULL,
    GL_FALSE); // disable all messages with source `GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION`
```

If you want to disable all error messages, except the API error messages, then you have to disable all messages first and the enable explicitly the API error messages:

```
glDebugMessageControl(
    GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, NULL, GL_FALSE);

glDebugMessageControl(
    GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API, GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, NULL, GL_TRUE);
```

See also [Debug Output - Message Components](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output#Message_Components)