# How to interpret GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT messages?

Tags: opengl, logging

I have installed OpenGL debug callback and enabled `GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT`. The callback looks like this:

```
void glMsgCallback( GLenum source,
                 GLenum type,
                 GLuint id,
                 GLenum severity,
                 GLsizei length,
                 const GLchar* message,
                 const void* userParam )
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "GL LOG: type = " << type << ", severity = " << severity << ", message = " << message;
    log(os.str());
}
```

And this is what I get in the log file:

```
GL LOG: type = 33361, severity = 33387, message = type: 1, local: 0, shared: 0, gpr: 6, inst: 18, bytes: 192
```

How do I interpret this data? Is there any way to discover which OpenGL function or feature is causing the message? I found out that type 33361 corresponds to `GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER`, and severity 33387 stands for `GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_NOTIFICATION`, but I'm oblivious of the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to discover which OpenGL function or feature is causing the message?

The debug callback can be called synchronously or asynchronously. See [Debug Output - Getting messages](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output#Getting_messages) Enable synchronously debug output:

```cpp
glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);
```

So you can set a breakpoint in the callback of the debug message and see on the call stack which function is causing the problem.

Furthermore the output can be filtered. See [How to use glDebugMessageControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962968/how-to-use-gldebugmessagecontrol/51963554#51963554). For example, limit the output to error messages:

```cpp
glDebugMessageControl(
    GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API, GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, NULL, GL_TRUE);
```